# Фильтр по выбранным данным

Tags: php, mysql

В общем, нужно реализовать фильтр по выбранным/введеным данным. Эти данные сохраняются в `Cookies` на 5 минут. Это удалось реализовать. Не удается сделать правильный вывод информации из БД.

---

В общем, вот код:

```
    /////////////куки фильтра
    if(isset($_POST['filter_spec'])){
        $sqlFilter = '';
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
            setcookie($key, $value, time() + 300);
        }
        header("Location: project.php");
    }

    echo '<div class="text">
        <form action="project.php" method="post" class="search_form" id="filter" name="filter">
        <input type="hidden" name="filter_spec" value="1"/>
            Страна: 
            <select name="countrys" class="styled" style="width: 220px">
                <option value="null">Выберите страну</option>';
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `country`");
while ($countrys = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
echo "<option ".is_sel($countrys['name'], 'countrys')." value='".$countrys['name']."'>".$countrys['name']."</option>";
}           
            echo '</select>
                Город: 
                <input class="selectbox form_input2" type="text" name="gorod" autocomplete="on" id="city" value="'.$_COOKIE['gorod'].'"/>
            <br/>
            Ключевые слова: 
            <input class="selectbox form_input1" type="text" name="text" value="'.$_COOKIE['text'].'"/>
            <br/>

            <div id="title_kat">
                <a class="pointer cursor_pointer specialitys_seatch_head" onclick="return showhide(1);">Требуемые Специализации </a>
                <br/>
                <div style="font-size:14px; padding-top:5px"> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="otd1" class="hide">
                <div class="choose_speciality">';
    $sqlCat = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM catalog");
while($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlCat)){
?>
 <script language="javascript"> function <?echo'view_'.$res['id'].'';?>() { var ele = document.getElementById("<?echo'views_'.$res['id'].'';?>"); var text = document.getElementById("<?echo'view_view_'.$res['id'].'';?>"); if(ele.style.display == "block") { ele.style.display = "none"; text.innerHTML = "<?echo'<b>'.$res['name'].'</b>';?>"; } else { ele.style.display = "block"; text.innerHTML = "<?echo'<b>'.$res['name'].'</b>';?>"; } } </script>
 <?
echo '<p><a href="#'.$res['name'].'"><label onclick="javascript&#058;view_'.$res['id'].'();" id="view_view_'.$res['id'].'"><b>'.$res['name'].'</b></label></a></p>';
$sqlPodCat = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM podcatalog WHERE id_cat={$res['id']}");
echo '<div id="views_'.$res['id'].'" style="border: 1px dotted #FFFFFF;overflow: auto;margin: 6px;border-radius:5px;padding:3px;display: none;">';
while($resPodCat = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlPodCat)){
echo '<input id="CheckBox'.$resPodCat['id'].'" class="CheckBoxClass" type="checkbox" value="'.$resPodCat['id'].'" name="cat[]"><label id="Label'.$resPodCat['id'].'" for="CheckBox'.$resPodCat['id'].'" class="CheckBoxLabelClass">'.$resPodCat['name'].'</label>'; 
} 
echo '</div>';
}
                        echo '<div id="otd41" class="spec">
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="otd_ten"></div>

            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="filter_spec" value="Включить фильтр" class="ok add_button" style="color:#5b5b5b; margin-bottom: -40px; margin-top: 10px"/>
            <input type="submit" name="clear" value="Очистить фильтр" class="ok add_button" style="color:#5b5b5b; float:right; margin-bottom: -40px; margin-top: 10px"/>

        </form>

        <br/>';
        echo '</div>';
echo '<br/><br/><div class="projects_search_content"><div class="sorting">Сортировать по дате: <div class="link_wrapper sorting_link_active1"><a href="" class="sorting_link">Самые новые</div> <div class="link_wrapper"><a href="?asc" class="sorting_link">Старые</a></div></div>';
//выводим заявки
$filter = "SELECT * FROM `project`";
////////////добавляем фильтр
if($_COOKIE['countrys'] > 0)
$filter .= " WHERE `countrys`=".$_COOKIE['countrys'];
if($_COOKIE['gorod'] > 0)
$filter .= " AND `gorod`=".$_COOKIE['gorod'];
if($_COOKIE['text'] > 0)
$filter .= " AND `text`=".$_COOKIE['text'];
if($_COOKIE['cat'] > 0)
$filter .= " AND `catalog`=".$_COOKIE['cat'];
$filter .= " ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT " . $start . "," . $message;
$sqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `project`";
if($_COOKIE['countrys'] > 0)
$sqlCount .= " WHERE `countrys`=".$_COOKIE['countrys'];
if($_COOKIE['gorod'] > 0)
$sqlCount .= " AND `gorod`=".$_COOKIE['gorod'];
if($_COOKIE['text'] > 0)
$sqlCount .= " AND `text`=".$_COOKIE['text'];
if($_COOKIE['cat'] > 0)
$sqlCount .= " AND `catalog`=".$_COOKIE['cat'];
$count = mysql_result(mysql_query($sqlCount), 0);
if($count>0) 
{
$req = mysql_query($filter); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
```

И тут идет дальше мой код.

Comment: Перед mysql_query($filter) выполните

    echo $filter;
    echo mysql_error();

А после еще раз

    echo mysql_error();

Comment: Фильтр не работает.

    SELECT * FROM `project` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,3 выходит

Comment: Сделал if(strlen($_COOKIE['countrys']))
$filter .= " WHERE `countrys`='".$_COOKIE['countrys']."'"; и т.д. и заработало.

Comment: Интересно, Вы сравниваете текстовые значение с заведомо с цифровым, равным 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверку делай с помощью конструкции isset() и будет щастье
Далее - у тебя код ваще не безопасный - экранировать нада данные поступающие из-вне перед тем как их в запрос кидать